# Intellij - How to automatically create a unit test for a groovy class

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij 10 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> works for java classes, but not Groovy classes.

Comment: Looks like a bug in IntelliJ, do not hesitate: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA

Comment: Works for me on 10.0.2. Did you already upgrade to that version?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be added in [Intellij 10.5](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/04/new-in-105-create-and-open-tests-for-groovy-classes-faster)